# External Content Type grab last rows of SQL table instead of first

Tags: filter, external-content-type, bdc

I'm working with a limit filter on an external content type that grabs the first 1000 rows of my table.  Is it possible to instead grab the LAST 1000 rows?

Comment: Have you considered reversing whatever sort you have on to change the last 1000 into the first 1000?

Comment: How can I do this?  Creating the filter in SharePoint Designer seems to just let me specify a default value to limit by and that's it. (aka.  If I set the default value to 100 it grabs the first 100 rows but I don't know how to reverse this)

Comment: let's say you have the rows sorted by ID, with 1 at the top. to grab the last 1000 rows, sort instead by ID #, Descending, and grab the first 1000 rows in this view.